# Can High Lumen Low Voltage Automotive LED Lights be safely powered with a Landscape Light Transformer in Exterior Light scenario

Tags: led, transformer

10 - 3000 lumen off road LED lights are 47 watts.  do not have volt amp drop rating. 470 watts

2 - 10/2 Low Voltage Landscape Lighting Wire - 10-Gauge 2-Conductor 100 Feet plus(whatever needed)

Use one of these transformers

- Kichler 15PR600SS Pro Series Transformer 600W, Stainless Steel
- VOLT 600W Clamp Connect Low Voltage Transformer with Timer/Photocell
- Best Pro Lighting 600W Multi Tap 120 Volt AC to 12-15 Volt LED & Halogen - Low Voltage Landscape
  Lighting Outdoor/Indoor

Exterior application along outside of elevated deck to provide light into yard and forested area around the property.

Centralized location for the transformer w 2 wire runs up to 100 ft. 4 to 6 lights on each run.

Can lights be run in a chain fashion with out dropping wattage.

if the light is 47 watts, 10 lights is 470 watts safe to use a 600 watt transformer ?

thoughts ?

Comment: That’s a lot of lighting. LED lights produce about as much light as an incandescent bulb of 6-7 times the wattage, so this is equivalent to over 3kW. Do you intend that much lighting?

Comment: My concern would be whether the power supply 6ou want to use can put out enough _amperage_ to drive those bulbs.

Answer (score 1):

If you match up voltage and DC polarity, you should be fine.  Note that transformers output AC.

Look closely at the automotive lights. If they spec 12-24 VDC, as many do, they are using a bucking switching DC/DC converter  (aka SMPS) to make the correct current for the LEDs. They will work on any voltage in that range and maybe a bit higher.

Note that voltage drop is a thing. On 12 volts, it's a BIG thing. Plinking random wire sizes on a hope and a prayer won't cut it, and results in the failure of many projects. You need a proper voltage drop calculation.

The ability of 12-24V automotive lights to work on any voltage in between is a great way to beat voltage drop. Start at 24 volts, which improves voltage drop by a factor of 4 anyway; and then even if voltage drop happens, as long as it's less than 50% drop the light won't care.

Comment: Random LED lights will also surprisingly often take anything between 12-24V either DC or AC, since they chop it up with a SMPS anyway.

Comment: @KMJ yeah I used different words to say that. But I wouldn't go so far as to say "all" - a lot of made-for-house-lighting stock uses the "3 LEDs and a resistor" style, which lends itself well to PWM dimming.

Comment: Some small 12v lights also have a pair of diodes in them so that they work when put in either way on a DC circuit.

Comment: IME automotive 12V LEDs often function in only one orientation...would running such on an AC output not trigger it only 50% of the time?

Comment: @Huesmann depends how smart the internal driver/SMPS (if any) is. Vehicle lights are expected to be wired correctly, no shop will ever have to take a vehicle light back because it doesn't work reversed lol.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I'm just talking about the bog standard LED replacement bulb here.  Put it in one way, it doesn't light; rotate 180º and no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Shopping is out of scope for this Stack Exchange so I'm not going to comment on your specific hardware choices.

As to running 12V LED lights off a 12V landscape power supply, I can't think of a reason why it would not work. You're going to need to be thoughtful about wire size as 600W is 50 amps. Probably lots of 12ga home runs will be a better bet.

Comment: If you do a bunch of home runs you also don't need a 600W PSU, you can use a bunch of smaller ones, it'll probably be cheaper.

Comment: True! Though high-wattage outdoor lighting power supplies are often fairly reasonably priced compared to smaller ones.

Comment: 8ga or 10ga is better than 12ga for longer runs

Comment: @Dave if these are 50 foot or under runs, one per light, it's overkill. At 47 watts (even if it's 47 'eBay watts') you're talking under five amps. https://www.bluesea.com/support/articles/Circuit_Protection/1437/Part_1%3A_Choosing_the_Correct_Wire_Size_for_a_DC_Circuit for a nice reference table.

Answer (score 0):

Your set up will work.  I have used the Automotive bulbs for just this  purpose.
The automotive bulbs lasted longer that the landscaping bulbs and were cheaper.
Use the heaver 12ga. wire.